# Sequelize Model class reference error in express application

Tags: express, sequelize.js

sq.js:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://chandan:duvarko315@localhost:5432/diary');

var User = sequelize.define('user', {
  username: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'username' // Will result in an attribute that is firstName when user facing but first_name in the database
  },
  password: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
},{
timestamps: false,
});

User.sync({force: true}).then(function () {
  // Table created  
});

module.exports = User;
```

app.js:

```
var seq = require('./routes/sq');

passport.use(new passportLocal.Strategy(function(username,password, done){
  User.findOne({username: username}, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null,{ id:username, name:username});
    });
}));
```

I am getting the error: ReferenceError: User is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because you have declared the user model as `seq` in app.js. Change your declaration to:

```
var User = require('./routes/sq');
```

The variable `User`only lives in sq.js

Comment: Yep that worked......but now the query is not executing......It displays in console as.......Executing (default): SELECT "id", "username", "password" FROM "users" AS "user" LIMIT 1;